# Страница перезагружается при отправке формы через ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Пытаюсь отправить запрос формы через ajax без перезагрузки страницы, но вот все равно не выходит.

Вот первый файл, который содержит ajax и саму форму

```
      <form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <textarea type="text" name="text" id="text" placeholder="Ваш текст..." class="text1"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit" style="border: 0;"><img class="im1" src="/default/отправить.png"></button>
      </form>
```

сам ajax

```
   <script>
   $(function () {
   $('#form').on('submit',function (e) {

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/chat.php',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
          });
      e.preventDefault();
        });
      });
      </script>
```

файл php

```
 <?php

 session_start();

 require "../server/config.php";

 if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $text = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']));
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];

  $query_chats=$db->query("INSERT INTO `chats`(`user_id`, `text`)
  VALUES ('$id', '$text')");

  $query_info_user_chats = $db->query("UPDATE chats
  INNER JOIN users
  ON chats.user_id = users.id
  SET chats.nickname = users.nickname, chats.avatar = users.avatar");
  
    header("Location:".$site_url."./modules/feed.php");
   }


   header("Location:".$site_url."./modules/feed.php");
   }
   else{
  header("Location:".$site_url);
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142898/discussion-on-question-by-user------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Насколько я знаю e.preventDefault(); должен стоять перед отправкой AJAX-запроса. Попробуй поставить строчку e.preventDefault(); перед $.ajax({.